# Bitmap generation with dot.net and png

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitmap, png, generator

What resources I need to look for, to generate one png image out of three?

Since there are sprite generators out there, that do not do what I want, I wanted to try by myself. The user interface should not be the problem, but i have no experience of generating bitmaps, especially those with transparent backgrounds. I will do that in .net. Thanks for any advice!

EDIT:

Thanks for asnwers. Let´s say I have 6 png files. I want to put them into one image, where there will be two rows of images in it, so 3 in row, 2 in height, 3*2. 
Every image might have a little different sizes, so i would need to fill up the space with, um, nothing...

Comment: What do you mean by "generate one png out of three"?

Comment: Don´t you know sprite generators @Nicolas?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the part about sprite generator in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps are very simple:
Create a Bitmap with the required dimensions, then use `Graphics.FromImage()` to obtain a graphics to draw on, then save the Bitmap with the desired format:

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200, 100);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.Clear(...);//fill with the base color
            //Draw here
            g.DrawLine(...);
            g.DrawImage(...); // to draw other images...
            bmp.Save("xxx.png",ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: thanks for answer felice, if you would like to review my edits above again?

Comment: Use DrawImage() in your snippet to clarify your answer.

Comment: @Luke well, you can call g.DrawImage(...) to draw the image on the target bitma ( obviously target bitmap should be big enougth ), before start dtawing you can call eg. g.Clear(Color.White) to fill the "dashboard" with one color